# Different Approaches to Derive Retail Prices?

Tags: excel, accounting

The question is not all about math, but how you might solve this situation.
Hopefully someone has dealt with this same issue and has an idea.

A manufacturer's client, the retailer, wants to make a certain markup on the final sales price based on ranges, here are sample costs to base them from.

[image]

500*1.75=875 retail for example

All of these retail prices are supposed to be derived from actual fixed costs all over the place and the expectation is that you can just multiply the cost by something to get the correct price markup when they go to sell it and guarantee the percentage they want

However everyone forgets that you markup 500 by 1.75 to get 875, but if you add one dollar to the cost
501*1.65=826.65
They somehow think the retail will magically ascend incrementally to match the cost scale.
Looking at final retail will always allow you to know the markup.

So I think the only solution is to never allow certain costs to occur, through rounding or averaging.

Surely someone else has dealt with this type of situation where management is telling you to just do it.
What would you do? 
How have you solved this?

Currently in excel, but could be in a db.

**Example of problem costs**

[image]

The all items that fall in the range highlighted in yellow are costs that make the retail drop below the previous retail. My solution thus far has been to round anything in these ranges UP to the value that SEEMS right.

For instance anything between 501-530 would round to 531, and anything between 1001-1064 would round to 1065

This just seems in-elegant and as you may have guessed some of these costs are not hundreds but thousands and the rounding is a poor solution at best.

What might be a better approach?

Comment: better suited to Super User rather than Stack Overflow which is for programming

Comment: In defense of this as programming, it is a calculation many dba's, and programmers may have addressed, more than an application specific question

Answer (score 1):

Put the boundaries where the lines intersect, or pick line slopes which cause the lines to intersect where you want the boundaries. A pricing model which doesn't meet this criterion has these "loopholes" which apparently your management doesn't want it to have. Perhaps you need to show them the problem graphically, and let them pick the option they prefer.

Comment: this is what I have tried so far, and +1 for the recommendations. Had hoped more people had this real life experience

Answer (score 1):

If the SIMPLE tier structure given in the other answer is too simple, then perhaps what you want is a complex "tiered" markup, where the first $500 get a markup of 1.75%, and THEN the 1.65% kicks in for the part over 500, and 1.55% applies to the part over 1000, etc.  This keeps the number from magically lowering as the prices move through the markup table.

This shows both solutions, notice the simple markup DOES allow the price to go down, while the TIERED markup does not:

**=SUMPRODUCT(--($B3>$F$2:$F$5), $B3 - $F$2:$F$5, $H$2:$H$5)** *(Tiered)*

vs.

**=B3 * VLOOKUP(B3,F:G, 2, 1) * A3** *(Simple)*

[image]

Comment: I have to test this with the data they have, but this is along the lines of exactly what I needed. Thanks

Comment: although I had hoped this would work, the markup ascends to counteract the problem. That poses a problem in calculating the invoice price based on retail. I think perhaps not allowing costs to ever fall in a range may be what I have to resort to.

Comment: If you want to present clearer examples of what your bosses WANT to happen in regards to pricing breaks near these edges of tiers, we might be able to help accomplish a clearly defined goal.

Comment: I think that is the problem. They think they want to reduce markup on higher cost goods, but when you show them the consequence, they won't accept that is right. So they never want things to act the way they will. So my inclination was to not ever have items COST what creates a problem, and perhaps I am wrong. I will try to edit this question to better reflect what is needed

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a programming problem, more of a straight VLOOKUP.  Using the sample pic below,

**=B2 * VLOOKUP(B2, F:G, 2, 1) * A2**

[image]

Comment: If you understood what I am asking it is not a vlookup problem. I have no problem finding the applicable markup. I have a problem with a 1 dollar change dropping the price by $50. Which I understand, but management doesn't. I guess I will have to ask this again, and perhaps one of the other sites

Comment: Well, currently, the math DOES drop the price by $50 when you go from $500 o $501, that's a common thing with simple tiered pricing.   What is the price they would LIKE it to be, let's try going from that approach.